# Как установить плагин robovm?

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь установить плагин robovm на android studio, при нажатии установка ничего не происходит. Как установить robovm?

Устанавливаю через стандартную установку плагинов

Comment: Зачем оно надо? RoboVM уже два с половиной года, как мертв.

Comment: @Эникейщик, А как сейчас сделанный в libgdx заливают на ios?